# Jquery : How to iterate in all links of a specific table row

Tags: jquery

suppose this is my table

```
<table border="1" id="tbl">
    <tr class="clsHead">
        <td>
            <a href="b.aspx">first row first cell</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="b.aspx">first row second cell</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="">seconde row</a>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

i tried this `jquery` but not working as expected. i was trying to change or modify href of those links in table row having class name **clsHead**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clsHead").each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
        $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+'&qString=1') ; 
    });
});
```

if possible tell me where i made the mistake. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to get/set the `href` attribute of each `.clsHead` element, and since it they don't have `href` attributes, it's clearly not working.

You need to select the descendant `a` elements instead:

```
$(".clsHead a").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '&qString=1');
});
```

Although it's shorter to just access the `href` property of `this`:

```
$(".clsHead a").each(function() {
  this.href = this.href + '&qString=1';
});
```

Or without jQuery:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.clsHead a');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el)  {
  el.href = el.href + '&qString=1';
});
```

You might need to wrap that logic in a DOM loaded event callback:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.clsHead a');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
    el.href = el.href + '&qString=1';
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
 $(".clsHead a").each(function ()
 {
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
  $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+'&qString=1') ; 
});
});
```